# Problem sorting divs using sort function inside jQuery each

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to sort inner elements inside parents.

In this simplified markup divs with class "down" supposed to go down (or up doesn't matter).
HTML

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="inner down">2</div>
    <div class="inner down">2</div>
    <div class="inner">1</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="inner">1</div>
    <div class="inner down">2</div>
    <div class="inner">1</div>
</div>
```

My code that supposed to work but nothing happens. Divs are not moving.

```
$('.parent').each(function(){
    var $elem = $(this).find('.inner').sort(function(a,b){
    return a.className < b.className;
    //return Math.random() >= 0.5; //doesn't make anything either
    });
    $(this).append($elem);
});
```

Desired output

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="inner">1</div>
    <div class="inner down">2</div>
    <div class="inner down">2</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="inner">1</div>
    <div class="inner">1</div>
    <div class="inner down">2</div>
</div>
```

I don't realy understand what's wrong with my code (jQuery 3.3.1 is in use). Any suggestion?

Comment: Sort expects a result of -1, 0, or 1.  Not true/false.  String comparisons should use the native `localeCompare()` String method

Comment: A better approach would be to make your view data driven. Imagine all you had to do was sort a data set, and your view would reflect it.

Comment: Thanks, @Taplar . To be more precise it expects a [number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort). -5, 0, 5 will do as well.

Comment: @Hebe I'm aware, but thanks for the follow up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get all elements with `down` class and then re-append them to move them to down.

```js
// use append method with callback to iterate over the 
// element and append the eleemnt which is returned
$('.parent').append(function() {
// get all element with class down witin the current parent
// specify context as this(this refers to current parent element)
  return $('.down', this)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="inner down">2</div>
  <div class="inner down">2</div>
  <div class="inner">1</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="inner">1</div>
  <div class="inner down">2</div>
  <div class="inner">1</div>
</div>
```